# How to use camel between to server and client's activemq

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am able to send messages from one queue to another queue in same activemq server.
But my requirement is :
a)There will be two host-  my system(as server) and virtual box(as client).
b)Both will have own activemq queue and camel.

Now the problem is -
how can I send message from server's queue to client's queue using server's camel?
and vice-verse.

please help me out. Any solution will be appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty basic concept to connect to different servers from a Camel instance. It, however, depends a bit on how you have it configured/deployed. Given you have your Camel running in Spring inside your ActiveMQ, you can simply setup two camel-activemq components. You need to give correct broker URLs, queue names etc.

```
<bean id="localamq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" >
        <property name="connectionFactory">
          <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?create=false"/>
            <property name="userName" value="${activemq.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}"/>
          </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="remoteamq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" >
        <property name="connectionFactory">
          <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://otherserver:61616"/>
          </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


  <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="localamq:some.queue"/>
            <to uri="remoteamq:some.other.queue"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Comment: Hi petter, thanks for you answer. But I am not using spring. Is it possible i servlets ?

Comment: Sure, however you configure Camel, be sure to fire up two `org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent`, each pointing to it's own `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` with the brokerURL set to each broker.

Comment: Thank you Petter. I would be very much thankful if you give me an example of activemq and camel in servlet. Thank you

Comment: No I have no such example, please update question with code that is not working if you want comments. However, my example with spring should be trivial to translate to whatever config method you want.